# Marionette.CompositeView how to pass a parameter to the template without using any model

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am in the following situation.

When the `collection.length = 0` I would like to pass a parameter to `listTemplate` in order to display a message in the `listTemplate` (no models are present!).
How can I achieve my goal?

Here's my code.

```
var ListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: listTemplate,
    // some code
});
```

---

```
var itemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    // some code
});
```

--

```
app.mainColumn.show(new ListView({
    collection: tasks,
    vent: myApp.vent
}));
```

Comment: You can use CollectionView's [emptyView](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-emptyview) to use a different view when the collection is empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you could redefine the `serializeData` method.

```
var ListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  template: listTemplate,
  serializeData: function(){
    viewData = { foo: 'foo' };
    if(this.collection.length == 0) viewData.bar = 'bar';
    return viewData;
  }
});
```

So in the template, `this.bar` is available (only if the collection is empty).

Answer (score 3):

You could programmaticly set which template to use and skip passing in a variable. 
For example:

```
getTemplate: function(){
    if (this.collection.length == 0){
        return "#no-models-are-present-template";
    } else {
        return "#regular-template";
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#change-which-template-is-rendered-for-a-view

Alternatively you could set an empty view
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-emptyview)
or use a template helper https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#object-or-function-as-templatehelpers
to achieve the same result.

Given that it's for an empty collection, I would use an empty view with a matching template.